# ¿Como indicar al usuario que un elemento en el array ya esta definido? (java)

Tags: java

¡Hola!, ya intente de todo pero no logro indicarle al usuario que un numero ya esta repetido en un array 
:( (mi nivel de programación es básico, estoy en primer año de desarrollo de software). Cree un método boolean para indicar al usuario que ya existe ese elemento, pero a la hora de la ejecución en Main es como si no existiera.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**1.- Clase Main**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestNumero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        Numero numP;
        int opc1, n, j=0, k = 0, numero = 0, dato;
        System.out.println("¿Cuantos numeros tendra el programa?");
        n = leer.nextInt();
        numP = new Numero(n);
        do {
            System.out.println("1.- Alta de numero");
            System.out.println("2.- Cambio de numero");
            System.out.println("3.- Eliminar un numero");
            System.out.println("4.- Imprimir numeros");
            System.out.println("5.- Salir");
            opc1 = leer.nextInt();
            switch (opc1) {
                case 1:
                    if (j<n) {
                        j++;
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el numero por favor");
                        numero=leer.nextInt();
                        numP.setNumero(k, numero);
                        if(numP.numeroRepetido(numero)){
                            System.out.println("Este numero ya esta repetido, ingresa otro");
                        }
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("No puedes agregar mas numeros");
                        }
                    break;
            }
        } while (opc1 < 4);
    }
}
```

**2.- Clase para los metodos**

```
public class Numero {

    private int arrayN[];

    Numero(int numero) {
        arrayN = new int[numero];
    }

    void setNumero(int i, int numero) {
        arrayN[i] = numero;
    }

    public boolean numeroRepetido(int numero) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
            if (arrayN[i]==numero) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    void borrarNumero(int posicion) {
        for (int i = posicion - 1; i < arrayN.length - 1; i++) {
            arrayN[i] = arrayN[i + 1];
        }
    }

    public int getNumero(int i) {
        return arrayN[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que en `numeroRepetido()` tienes la lógica al revés, pues cuando está repetido retornas `false` y cuando no lo está retornas `true`. Por otro lado, haces el `setNumero()` antes de la verificación, lo cual tampoco es correcto, deberías hacerlo dentro del `if` y hacer la verificación en negativo, o sea preguntar si no está repetido para entonces agregarlo.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por contestar!, seguiré los consejos :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes la condición al revés. Devuelves `false` cuando debería ser `true` y viceversa.

En el `switch` deberías validar primero que el número no existe y luego hacer el *set* tal como indica el compañero en comment.

```
 switch (opc1) {
   case 1:
     if (j < n) {
       j++;
       System.out.println("Ingrese el numero por favor");
       numero = leer.nextInt();

       if (!numP.numeroRepetido(numero)) {
         numP.setNumero(k, numero);
       } else {
         System.out.println("Este numero ya esta repetido, ingresa otro");
       }
     } else {
       System.out.println("No puedes agregar mas numeros");
     }
   break;
 }
```

```
 public boolean numeroRepetido(int numero) {
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayN.length; i++) {
     if (arrayN[i]==numero) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: Ese es el primer error, pero en el `switch` también tiene un error de lógica, porque está haciendo el `setNumero` sin saber antes si está repetido  o no. Debería preguntas en negativo y dentro del `if` hacer el `setNumero`

Comment: gracias. He actualizado la respuesta con lo que comentabas

Comment: ¡Wow!, me ha explotado la cabeza. ¡Muchas gracias por su apoyo! :)